# Firebase doesn't work in Capacitor iOS build from Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have built an application using Ionic React and have added an iOS build via Capacitor.

Everything works on the web build, but Firebase stops working on the iOS build.

The build is successful and network requests appear to be firing, but anything related to Firebase (auth and any firestore requests) appear to load infinitely.

I am using Firebase v9 and have tried the following as a fix:

```
// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function whichAuth() {
  let auth;
  if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
      persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence,
    });
  } else {
    auth = getAuth();
  }
  return auth;
}

export const firebaseAuth = whichAuth();
export const db = getFirestore();
export const firebaseAnalytics = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);
```

Comment: I recently posted the same. Nobody is answering. On iOS, I have the same problem. When it touches Firebase code, it stops or hangs in there.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any fix ?. However i am getting response for error inscenarios, for ex: if i enter incorrect email.. then the api is giving the response as error.

Comment: I’m suffering this issue too, I’ve spent all day looking for a solution, I’ve ended authenticating using capacitor plugins but FireStore and other services remain unauthenticated. My firebase instance at least does not hangs but I’m always getting a permission denied response (I’m porting an web app that already works and have all rules defined)

I’ll keep looking tomorrow with fresher eyes, but I would say that the Token is issued for http meanwhile we are using capacitor. Just my guess after thinking for a while

Comment: I got it working finally, it's been replied here :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/74974461/7415790