# FirebaseAuthentication Plugin not updating local FireBase.Auth JS with signed in user

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

## Background

I have an almost finished webapp already working with the following stack

- Firebase
- React/TypeScript

## Context

I'm adding Capacitor to my WebApp so I have a native app where I can send push notifications, and have presence in App Store, Google Play Store. The application already works on its web version, so there is no rule (Real Time Database, FireStore, etc) problem, no credentials problems at all on its web version, all well tested.

## Problem

I've added Authentication to my application via Firebase Authentication, which works well, and I have also connected the Native iOS version to it, as it's described in the [documentation](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase)

Auth flows works fine, User/Password & Google sign up are working fine and actually triggering the methods like **onIdTokenChange** and **OnAuthStateChange** from the official Firebase Auth library, in both cases, iOS and WebApp, and also the **OnAuthStateChange** from the Capacitor plugin (in both clients too).

The problem is that the Firebase JS library remains somehow in a unauthenticated state, where any call to FireStore, Database, or Storage, ends up in "Permissions Denied" error (Only on iOS). Once the Token ID has changed, I can see that currentUser is NULL, and the "signed in user" is not propagating to the Firebase official library from the Capacitor Plugin.

Once I have connected the Capacitor Firebase Authentication plugin, I was expecting that the Firebase official JS library was going to be updated, I've also used Firebase Authentication with IndexedDB local persistence as follows (when being in Native) as follows:

```
export const Authentication = Capacitor.isNativePlatform() ? initializeAuth(FirebaseApp, {
  persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
}) : getAuth(FirebaseApp);
```

Comment: Did you follow this guide? https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/authentication/docs/firebase-js-sdk.md

Comment: You are right, that's exacrtly the missing part I was missing, I couldn't find where the missing part/conexion was. Kudos for you! Thank you very much!